# How to calculate DynamoDB RCUs for a CSV import?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am planning on ingesting a 200,000 sized csv into dynamodb which would be done very infrequently. The items are not going to cross 1KB from estimates. While I understand the CSV formula for RCUs and WCUs - I wanted to see how we can turn this use case into calculating the RCU and WCU for the table?

For writes:

```
1 WCU = 1 write per second for 1KB item
```

So if we have 50 writes (non transactional) -> it should be 50 WCUs. But how do we arrive at the actual WCU (Im just using 50 here as an example) - how would a 200,0000 csv import translate into actual writes ? Do I have to assumed 200,0000 would be imported in one straight operation thus our WCU is `200000` which would seem a lot for a 1 time write operation)

Answer (score 0):

Think of WCUs as the number of (sub-1k) rows per second that you want. If you specify 100, it’ll take 2,000 seconds to load. Any requests you send beyond 100 per second will be throttled (return an error). If you specify 1,000, it’ll take 200 seconds to load. And so on.

You can scale up and scale down as needed based on your activity.

If you’re loading the CSV to a new table you can use the new Import from S3 feature also. That’s priced per GB loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to automate an S3 load into DynamoDB? Lets say we add the 200k row csv file into s3 -> could i accomplish this automatically via , say, S3 put even trigger -> Lambda -> S3 import to Dynamo?

Comment: There’s a native Import from S3 feature now. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-can-now-import-amazon-s3-data-into-a-new-table/